# Notice undefined index Error PHP

Tags: php, html

Tengo un problema con mi código, resulta que cuando le doy un valor a mi variable $mes , me lo saca todo bien, y tengo puesto que en el caso de que $mes tenga un valor null o esté vacío, me saque el mes actual, y me lo saca bien. El problema es que en la parte superior me sale el mensaje de `Undefined index: id_mes` , aunque yo creo que no lo requiero ya que tengo puesto lo de isset y !empty, me lo saca todo bien pero el mensaje me sale ahí arriba, y no entiendo porque.

A ver si alguien me puede ayudar echándole un vistazo, porque no consigo verlo, la verdad.

```html
<script src="js/semanal.js"></script>

<?php
if (strpos(getcwd(), 'apen_files') !== false) {
 define('_PS_ADMIN_DIR_', getcwd());
} else {
 define('_PS_ADMIN_DIR_', getcwd().'/includes/apen_files/');
}
 require (_PS_ADMIN_DIR_."/config.php"); 
 
 //-----------------------------------------------------
 $any = $_POST['id_anio']; 
 $mesac=date ("F");
$mes = $_POST['id_mes'];
$nomdia=date ("l");
$dia = $_POST['id_day'];
$date= "".$dia."-".$mes."-".$any;
 ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/estilo.css"/>
<div id="principal_pordias">
 
</div>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<?php $meses = array("ENERO", "FEBRERO", "MARZO", "ABRIL", "MAYO", "JUNIO", "JULIO", "AGOSTO", "SEPTIEMBRE", "OCTUBRE", "NOVIEMBRE", "DICIEMBRE"); ?>
<?php $dias = array('', 'LUNES','MARTES','MIÉRCOLES','JUEVES','VIERNES','SÁBADO', 'DOMINGO'); ?>
<?php function saber_dia($date) {
$dias = array('', 'LUNES','MARTES','MIÉRCOLES','JUEVES','VIERNES','SÁBADO', 'DOMINGO');
$fecha = $dias[date('N', strtotime($date))];
echo $fecha;
} ?>
<p>
<div><center>
<?php echo $any; ?>
</center></div>
<p>
<div><center>
<?php
if ($mes && !empty($mes)) {
    echo $meses[$mes -1];
}
else {
 echo $meses[date('n')-1];
}
?>
</center></div>
<p>
<div><center>
<?php echo $dia; ?>
</center></div>
<p>
<div><center>
<?php
if ($mes && !empty($mes)) {
saber_dia($date); }
else {
 echo $dias[date('w')];
}
?>
</div></center>
    <div id="fecha"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda una vez más.

Mi código AJAX del cual recibo las variables 'id':

```js
function select_pordias(dia, anio, mes) { 
    $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: 'includes/apen_files/recarga_agenda_pordias.php',
                    data: {
                     id_anio:anio,
      id_mes:mes,
      id_day:dia
                        },
                    success: function (response) {
      //alert (response);
                        $('#body_center').html(response);
                        }
              });
     
 }
```

```js
if(i<primerDiaSemana)
  {
   // celda mes anterior y siguiente
   resultado+="<td class='ayer'><a class='ayer' onclick='select_pordias(this.id,"+year+","+month+")'>"+(ultimoDiaMesAnt - (primerDiaSemana - i - 1))+"</a></td>";
   
  } else if (i>=last_cell) {
  if (i % 7 == 0) {
                  resultado+="<td class='post' style='color: #fd9292'><a class='red' onclick='select_pordias(this.id,"+year+","+month+")'>"+a+++"</a></td>";
                  } else {
                    resultado+="<td class='post' style='color: #cccccc'><a class='post' onclick='select_pordias(this.id,"+year+","+month+")'>"+a+++"</a></td>";
                  }
      }
   else{
   // mostramos el dia
   if(dia==actual.getDate() && month==actual.getMonth()+1 && year==actual.getFullYear())
    resultado+="<td class='hoy' ><a class='hoy' onclick='select_pordias(this.id,"+year+","+month+")' id="+ dia +">"+dia+"</a></td>";
   else
    resultado+="<td><a class='negro' onclick='select_pordias(this.id,"+year+","+month+")' id="+ dia +">"+dia+"</a></td>";
   dia++;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No basta poner:

```
if ($mes && !empty($mes)) {
    echo $meses[$mes -1];
}
```

Si quieres evitar el error, tendrías que poner, al principio:

```
$mes = isset($_POST['id_mes'])? $_POST['id_mes'] : null;
```

o algo similar.

Answer (score 0):

```
$mes = $_POST['id_mes'];
```

revisa si esa varible `'id_mes'` que recibe en el `$_POST` esta definida

Comment: Sí, las obtengo a través de un AJAX. Las variables id_mes, id_day, id_anio las recoge del mismo AJAX, entonces no entiendo porque solo me da el undefined index del 'id_mes'...

Comment: podrias colocar entonces el codigo de tu AJAX, para poder tener mejor claridad acerca de lo que deseas hacer.

Comment: Ahi te lo he añadido, pero no me explico porque solo me dice undefined index al id_mes ... Gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: revisa, si lo que te devuelve "recarga_agenda_pordias.php", tienes definida esa variable 'id_mes'

Comment: Perdón pero no te entiendo, "recarga_agenda_pordias.php" es el código que he colgado. Lo único que he definido es `$mes = $_POST['id_mes'];` , si es eso a lo que te refieres. Disculpa mi desconocimiento

Comment: disculpa creo q me exprese mal, una consulta, de donde recibes los campos, que llama a tu funcion function select_pordias(dia, anio, mes)

Comment: Te lo añado al post principal

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79157/discussion-between-vanesa-claros-and-joume-parra).